# Not displaying a component for a specific route in React-Router-DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using React-Router-DOM v6.19.0 in my React app. I have a `Layout` for the routes in Root.jsx:

```
function Root() {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <Outlet />
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}

export default Root
```

This is being shown in my main routes in Main.jsx:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
        <Route path='/' element={<Root />}>
          <Route path='' element={<Home />}/>
          <Route path='about' element={<About />}/>
          <Route path='pinboard' element={<Todos />}/>
          <Route path='lists' element={<Lists />}/>
        </Route>
    )
)

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
)
```

As you can see, the header and footer are being rendered in each route, with only the `Outlet` changing.

The problem is, I don't want to display the header and footer on a specific route (like the sign-up page).

How can I achieve this?

I tried to make a condition check:

```
const location = useLocation();

const DontRenderHeaderFooter = ['/login', '/signup'];
const renderHeaderFooter = !DontRenderHeaderFooter.includes(location.pathname);

return (
    <>
        {renderHeaderFooter && <Header />}
        <Outlet />
        {renderHeaderFooter && <Header />}
    </>
)
```

But that didn't seem to work.

Comment: The simpler solution would be to just move the routes you don't want to render with the header/footer ***outside*** the layout route that renders the header/footer. 0stone0's suggestion *will* work, but is a little convoluted and not very ***DRY*** (***D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `<Wrapper />` component that will *wrap* some component in the Header + Footer.

---

So in this example we Wrap every component in the Header + Footer, except the `<Home />` component, that will just render itself. (The login route you mention in the question)

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
        <Route path='/' element={<Wrapper><Home /></Wrapper>}>
          <Route path='' element={<Home />}/>
          <Route path='pinboard' element={<Wrapper><Todos /></Wrapper>}/>
          <Route path='lists' element={<Wrapper><Lists /></Wrapper>}/>
        </Route>
    )
)

const Wrapper = (props) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        {props.children}
        <Footer />
    <React.Fragment>
)
```